# all: initial vs. using CSS resets

Tags: css, reset

I know there are many so-called "css resets", e.g.

- https://ageek.dev/normalize-css,
- https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/, or
- https://elad2412.github.io/the-new-css-reset/

But what I don't understand is why it seems it is not possible to use something way more simpler.

As far as I know, the `initial` keyword resets a property to the value that is defined as the default value of that property in the CSS specification.

And since nowadays we have the `all` property-like keyword, I expected that I can use something like

```
* {
  all: initial;
}

or

:root {
  all: initial;
}
```

instead of all these `reset.css`s and `normalize.css`s. That is, I expected that one of these short snipets will help me to remove styles added to a web page from user agent stylesheet.

But it doesn't really work as I expected it. It seems that

```
:root, html, body {
  all: initial
}
```

doesn't really remove styles "inherited" from user agent stylesheet at all, and

```
* {
  all: initial
}
```

removes styles too aggressively. For example, it makes my `style` and `script` elements visible! I don't think that CSS specification says that these two elements should be visible. I'm sure that CSS specification says that they should be **not** visible. That is, it seems that

```
* {
  all: initial
}
```

instead of resetting my styles to the CSS specification-level, resets them to the absolute-zero-level. This is not what I want.

---

Can anybody explain what is wrong in my understanding?

Comment: each browser has its own "initial" predefined styling. with resets, you get the same experience regardless of browser...within reason.

Comment: _"I'm sure that CSS specification says that they should be not visible."_  Really?  I'm not sure of that at all.  In fact, I was under the impression that the spec might define default values for CSS properties _in general_, but not scoped to specific elements.  For example, [the `<script/>` spec document linked from MDN](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element) doesn't have any mention any styling that I noted at a glance.  I'm happy to be proven wrong in my assumption-- do you have any examples where element style defaults are defined in a spec?

Comment: @AlexanderNied No, I don't have examples. My guess is based on how I understand MDN pages. See the 1st paragraph [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) and then [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial_value). The 1st page says that using `initial` keyword means initial value (duh!), and the second page says the following: "The initial value of a CSS property is its default value, **as listed in its definition table in the specification**". Note the bold text!

Comment: Sure-- I do think that this is the source of the misunderstanding you are having about how `initial` works.  I have provided an answer with some additional references that might better illustrate this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) resets to initial values for a given CSS property, but note that CSS properties have no initial value *for each element*-- they only have an initial value for that *property*, which will be the same for any and all elements it is applied to.  For instance, [the `color` property spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#the-color-property) has a single initial value defined-- not a list of initial values to which it should be set for every element.  So when you use it in conjunction with [`all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all), using:

```css
* {
  all: initial
}
```

...you are telling the browser to take every property of every single element and reset it to the *property's* default value.  So, for instance, the [`display` property spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#the-display-properties) defines its initial value as `inline`-- so *every single element* on your page will be displayed as `inline`.